# Node & Token Based Security

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt

I'm building a node web app which includes a user authentication API.

Every tutorial I've read online outlines using something like a config file to store a server secret which is used to generate a jwt, which then gets passed to the client who uses it until expiry for authentication.

My issue is in the concept of having one key stored somewhere - anywhere really - from which all tokens are generated. I feel as though if anybody gets this secret, they could spoof tokens, e.g. for other users, etc.

Couldn't there be a more sophisticated system, such as multiple secrets, for every individual user, or maybe even every individual token, and then these multiple secrets are stored in their own separate database collection. This way, if anybody every figured out a single secret, it may limit the damage to only a specific token which will expire eventually anyways?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having one secret which you must protect, now you have 10,000 separate ones (for 10,000 users)?  That are stored in a DB?  Also the call to the DB every time to read the JWT would add another latency just to decode the JWT.

Then comes to the 2nd issue.  How do you know which one to look up?  With a JWT signed with a single secret, you can open it, get the userid and lookup the user.

But with a JWT signed with an unknown secret, you would need some other way to know which user this was.  UserID in the URL? another posted value?  Then do a lookup?

3rd: You open yourself up to someone hammering you with invalid tokens.  In your scenario if you get hit with 100,000 bad tokens, you have to query the database 100,000 times to try to find passwords for them?  If you had a single secret key (that node had in memory) it would identify the bad tokens quickly and send them to the login screen,  Thus not hammering your database and affecting your valid users.

Comment: So assuming a brute force attack to figure out the one secret isn't feasible if that secret is complex enough?

Comment: Ye.  But more of brute force isnt feasible with the limited number of attempts you would permit them.  Brute force attacks can be mitigated as well with other techniques.  Such as if an IP sends you invalid tokens XX times in a row, then you ban their IP for an hour or longer.    I'm sure there are other threads on this site with more ideas.

Comment: How do you handle the scenario of "developer turning into attacker"? Say you have some disgruntled employee who leaves the team, couldn't he take advantage and start spoofing tokens? There needs to be a better way...but apart from the random DB approach, I am kinda out of ideas... :(

Comment: @Ashish You can always change the secret.  New tokens would be signed with the new secret and all old tokens are invalid.  Users must login again.  Or you could keep the old one valid for X period of time while you switch over to the new secret.  The users would get issued a new token once the server noticed they signed had an old one.  Seamless Secret changover.  Realistically if you wanted you could have the secret always moving, rotating on a schedule (daily) and allowing the former secret to be used for a period of time so that the exchange could happen.